# No data displayed in oracle custom form r12.1.3

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

I have developed a sample custom form in R12.1.3.
After form registration I am not getting any data.

[image]

Comment: There's no way we can remotely debug your Form. Sorry but you're going to have to step through your code and figure out what the problem is. The place to start is, do you have data in the table? Are you connecting to the right schema?

Comment: Is your data block bounded to a DB table? does it have a `WHERE` clause? in which trigger do you issue your EXECUTE_QUERY command? do your logged user has the appropriate privileges on the table?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and suggestion.

I have resolved the issue. we need to run below script before generating the .fmx file.

FORMS_PATH=$APPL_TOP/au/12.0.0/resource:$APPL_TOP/au/12.0.0/forms/US:$APPL_TOP/au/12.0.0/resource/stub;export FORMS_PATH